# Correct Breadcrumbs Structure with child

Tags: schema, breadcrumbs

Which one is correct breadcrumb structure?

Example 1:

```
  <a href="http://example.com/topic" itemprop="url">
  <span itemprop="title">Topic Archive</span></a>

  <div itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" style="display: inline;">
    <a href="http://example.com/topic/parent-category" itemprop="url">
    <span itemprop="title">ParentCategory</span></a>
  </div>

  <div itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" style="display: inline;">
    <a href="http://example.com/child-category" itemprop="url">
    <span itemprop="title">Child Category</span></a>
  </div>

  <span>Post Title Goes Here</span>

</div>
```

Example 2:

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
    <span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a rel="home" href="http://www.example.com/topic" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Topic Archive</span></a> ›

        <span itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/topic/parent-category/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Parent Category</span></a> ›

          <span itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/topic/child-category/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Child Category</span></a> ›
            </span>

        <span>Post Title Goes Here</span>
        </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Example 3:

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
    <span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a rel="home" href="http://www.example.com/topic" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Topic Archive</span></a> ›

        <span itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/topic/parent-category/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Parent Category</span></a> ›

          <span itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/topic/child-category/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Child Category</span></a> ›


          <h1 itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/topic/child-category/current-post-link" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Current Post Title</span></a> ›
            </h1>          

          </span>
        </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Test the code here: [Google Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/)

For example number 3, is it right to include the current page in breadcrumb schema? Do I violate any rules?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use data-vocabulary.org (which is already considered outdated), example 3 is the most correct.  It is standard to include the current page in the breadcrumb.  Example 1 is not correct since you have not nested your elements.  In this case, you would want to add the `itemref` property and give ids to your divs.  The `itemref` property should equal the id of the next child.  https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs?rd=1

You should definitely consider moving to schema.org, since that is the format the major search engines will almost certainly agree upon.  According to schema.org, none of these are the proper implementation.  Your overall list should be marked as a BreadcrumbList, with each item being marked as a ListItem.  Yes, by convention, the current page is the last item in the list.

https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList

Comment: Yes I'm aware that my example is different from schema.org structure. I'm using data-vocabulary.org, just want to know if this what is the correct format when using the data-vocabulary.org structure in breadcrumbs.

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs?rd=1 ...

`Note: This article describes an older format. Schema.org markup for breadcrumbs is being finalized and will be preferred when ready.`

...and from http://www.data-vocabulary.org/ ...

`Since June 2011, several major search engines have been collaborating on a new common data vocabulary called schema.org.`

Why are you using a format that is outdated and already considered an old format?

Comment: is there something wrong if I use the data-vocabulary.org for my breadcrumbs?
did you also read the important note on the link you post?
Important: Breadcrumb markup with schema.org is not yet supported.

That's why I'm going to use data-vocabulary for now. :)

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with it, only it will be deprecated in the near future and also isn't supported in all of the browsers.  Just keep an eye on it and be prepared to switch once the schema.org standard is supported by all the major browsers.  I updated my answer to include information about the data-vocabulary.org syntax.  Hopefully it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful answer. I really appreciate it Shawn. One last question, on example 3 as you can see I also added itemprop="child" and stuff on the current page title. Is that how you do it or the current page must not have any data-vocab syntax?

Comment: The current page is part of the breadcrumb and therefore should also contain the data-vocab information.